# How to save image to Phone gallery from image URL in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, image

I have build an App in AngularJS +  Ionic.In this App there is an Image against each record and i want to give option to user to save that image to its Mobile Image Gallery.

Any idea how i can do this?

Thanks